# Write proof by contradiction with formal notation

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I wanted to write a proof by contradiction in general with formal notations and after some thought, i wrote this:
$$P\rightarrow (Q\ \wedge\sim Q)\vdash\sim P$$

Is this correct?

Comment: What you have written is proof of negation, not proof by contradiction.

Comment: Note that you have accepted a somewhat wrong answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an expression of *reductio ad absurdum* from Wikipedia {[Proof by Contradiction](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contradiction)}. It's exactly like yours, except for the *symbolic representation* of a *contradiction* (*vide* Note)

$(p \implies \bot) \implies \neg p$

Note: $\bot = (q \land \neg q)$

I prefer the following version:

$(\neg p \implies \bot) \implies p$

**EDIT START** (based on comments)

The correct expression is:

$(p \vdash \bot) \vdash \neg p$

**EDIT END**

Comment: The two versions you list are not necessarily equivalent. They are only equivalent in the presence of LEM

Comment: Why, may I ask?

Comment: @AgentSmith Nice, but i prefer $\vdash$ symbol instead of $\implies$.

Comment: @AgentSmith the second version relies on double negation (which is equivalent to LEM). Really the immediate conclusion of the second version is $\neg\neg p$. But then we apply double negation elimination to conclude $p$.

Comment: Also @Amin , be careful: the two symbols usually do not mean the same thing and are not interchangeable. Though here it is probably harmless

Comment: @IsAdisplayName Yes, I know. when we say "Proof by contradiction", we are talking about "Proof" and also $\vdash$ symbol is about proving. So in this case, $\vdash$ is better choice than $\implies$.

Comment: @IsAdisplayName, How are *double negation* and *LEM* connected? All I'm aware of is that *reductio ad absurdum* is a result of *the law of noncontradiction* (LNC) and the LNC = LEM.

Comment: Double negation is equivalent to LEM.

Comment: You shouldn't be writing this post if you don't actually know the topic well! None of what you wrote is actually correct, neither your original nor your edit!

Comment: @user21820, do post the correct answer then. Danke.

Comment: I will iff the asker unaccepts yours. Briefly: (1) We must clearly distinguish between internal implications and external deductive rules. (2) Logicians generally consider proof by contradiction to be expressed by either the rule ( ( ¬P ⊢ ⊥ ) ⊢ P ) or the rule ( ( ¬P⇒⊥ ) ⊢ P ).